# Infinite redirect - nginx

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, vhosts, ghost

I seem to be having an issue with an infinite redirect with nginx.  This has been driving me crazy for the las half hour or so because I am unable to identify where the infinite redirect is occurring.

### vHost:

```
Server ID : SuperUser Shell : sites-available/ > # cat example.com-ssl 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return      301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return      301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

    # This is for troubleshooting
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/error.log debug;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl                         on;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com/2017/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com/2017/www.example.com.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com/2017/www.example.com.ca-bundle;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_dhparam                 /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com/2017/dhparam.pem;
    add_header                  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubexamples; ";

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/error.log;
}
Server ID : SuperUser Shell : sites-available/ > #
```

### Additional info:

I should also point out that this is a ghost blogging server and that I have updated `config.js` to reflect https instead of http:

```
Server ID : SuperUser Shell : ghost/ > # cat config.js 
// # Ghost Configuration
// Setup your Ghost install for various [environments](http://support.ghost.org/config/#about-environments).

// Ghost runs in `development` mode by default. Full documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org/config/

var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {

    // ### Production
    production: {

        url: 'https://www.example.com',
        mail: {},

        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },

    // ### Development **(default)**
    development: {

        url: 'https://www.example.com',

        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
    },

...

Server ID : SuperUser Shell : ghost/ > #
```

**I also restarted this java process using `pm2` (What I use to keep ghost running).  I even went as far as stopping the process and starting it again**

### cURL output:

```
... Same thing as below for 49 times
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.example.com/'
* Found bundle for host www.example.com: 0x263b920
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.example.com
* Connected to www.example.com (123.45.67.89) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sat, 26 Nov 2016 08:56:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 63
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Location: https://www.example.com/
< Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; 
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.bestredflags.com left intact
* Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

### Questions:

- Does anyone see where I am making my mistake?
- I copied my nginx configuration from my RHEL 7.3 server running `nginx version: nginx/1.10.2` (where there are no issues) to my Ubuntu 14.04 running `nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)` could this be part of my problem?

  - I did not receive an error from `nginx -t` before pushing the vHost config change.
  - This leads me to think that there is not an issue with my vHost but a vHost misconfiguration also seems to be the logical choice.
- Something that I was wondering about earlier is that this seems quite a bit longer in nginx than redirecting `null` to `www` to `https://www` is in apache.  **Am I doing this right for nginx?**

  - I am following documentation put forth here:
    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

I hope that this is not too much information. I definitely don't want to give too little information.

**Thanks for any help / pointers.**

Comment: I guess that your service at `http://127.0.0.1:2368;` is trying to redirect to https - not realising that its behind a reverse proxy. You may need to set additional headers, like `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` (assuming that your application knows how to use them).

Comment: It turns out that I had two issues.  There was one with my Ghost config and one with CloudFlare when I re-enabled it.  Thanks for reaching back and trying to help me out though.  I have to wait 2 days before accepting my answer, but if you want to post an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super embarrassing but I found out when comparing configs that my production server that ghost does not need to have `https` specified in `config.js`.  This caused my first infinite redirect loop.

```
PROD : SuperUser Shell : ghost/ > # grep sitename config.js 
        url: 'http://www.sitename.com',
        url: 'http://www.sitename.com',
PROD : SuperUser Shell : ghost/ > #
```

Secondly I received another redirect loop from CloudFlare when re-enabling DNS Protection

- To correct this issue go to the Overview tab > Settings Summary > Click on SSL and change SSL from "Flexible " to "Full (Strict)".